# How to skip language selection in Game Center Leaderboards?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, game-center, gamekit

I only have one language, English, and I don't want my users to have to click on English each time they want to see the high scores.  Is there a way to select certain leaderboards from code?

I am using Unity's Social API, but I suspect I will need to do this from XCode.

[image: Screenshot of Leaderboard first screen]

[image: Image from iTunes Connect]

Comment: i've never seen a language selection inside game center. can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: @JeanLuc I edited it to add that, and also a screenshot from iTunes Connect

Answer (score 1):

You named the leaderboard „English“, usually it is named „Best time“ or „Points score in game mode X“.

Anyway if you want to directly show a specific leaderboard, you can call this static method:

SocialPlatforms.GameCenter.GameCenterPlatform.ShowLeaderboardUI(...)

As first parameter you to set the id of your leaderboard. The second one is the time scope.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SocialPlatforms.GameCenter.GameCenterPlatform.ShowLeaderboardUI.html

**UPDATE 1:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms.GameCenter;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public void OnClickedLeaderboardButton()
    {
        GameCenterPlatform.ShowLeaderboardUI("YOUR_LEADERBOARD_ID",TimeScope.AllTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, my bad.  The window says "Edit Language."  I didn't realize I was editing the leaderboard name.  So I changed it to "High Scores".  I'm already showing the leaderboard using the ID, but is there a way to automatically show "High Scores" without the user having to click on it?

Comment: does calling GameCenterPlatform.ShowLeaderboardUI(...) work? make sure you use the proper Leaderboard ID that you defined, which might be different from the Leaderboard name.